# Browser's service worker gives easy access to make botnets?

Tags: security, browser, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, browser-security

I've been reading about service workers to use some of its features for my app to be more fast and reliable. While I got excited as I see through the possibilities of service workers and persistant storage enabline webapp to have all native app capabilities, I also had this thought.

What if someone who wants to make a botnet? They just send their website link to some users, that's all, service workers get installed in a number of browsers all across the world. Now the site owner can do many things with this bot net like making a ddos attack, crypto mining etc. I think it might even make it easier for a hacker trying to exploit some browser vulnerability.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The web and browser security models have a number of measures in place to prevent or limit abuse.

1) [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a web security feature that limits or makes it difficult for websites/service workers to DDOS attacks on other domains.

2) Service workers have a [maximum runtime of five minutes](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/service-worker-security-faq.md#do-service-workers-live-forever) (in Chrome but other browsers should have similar limits). After five minutes the SW will be killed and the user will have to trigger an event before the service worker will be reactivated.

3) Most browsers use [Safe Browsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/) to block access to malicious sites so it would be quick to disable globally.

This all assumes that "They just send their website link to some users" is easy to pull off. Email spam filters are really good these days and SMS is expensive so getting a PWA to a large number of user would be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. The article on "maximum runtime of five minutes" is very useful.Does it mean that I cannot push notification after 5 minutes of users' non-interaction with my site?

Comment: @abraham note that cors will not prevent a request a different domain, it prevents the response from being read, but that's not relevant for preventing ddos.

Comment: @ManiBharathy push notifications can wake up a SW but will need the user to allow them.

Comment: @GaborLengyel it depends on the type of request. Some requests will instead have a pre-flight request that should in theory have less effect on destination servers. Plus they would be much easier for anti-DDOS software to filter out.

Comment: @abraham So for every push notifcation a permission pop up hits the user? Wouldn't that make a bad user experience?